# Replacing text within a filtered range

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Can someone please provide me with an effective approach for the following as I'm currently using a "Very" long winded approach.

I have applied a filter / I have set a dynmaic range for the filtered data - e.g:

```
Set rngToCut = Sheets(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName).Range(Sheets(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName).Cells(2, 1), _
Sheets(gcsCombinedKycExportsSheetName).Cells(Lrow, 1)).EntireRow
```

For each row in the filter I want to replace the contents of Column A with the text "ISSUE".  Currently I'm skipping through them line by line but this is very slow with the volume of data I have.

Any good suggestions PLEASE?

Thanks,

Ciaran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Substitute` function is designed to replace a substring of a string.

Have you tried to create a calculated field, populated with the new string values, and then used `PasteValues` on the original Range to replace the values of the original field?

Comment: THanks Justin - I appreciate your help. cheers.  I just tried the substiture and it works fine.  However I still need to skip through each cell.  When using a filter is their any way to say substitute all the visable cells in column A with "ISSUE" etc?  Thanks